# How to build a facade of an existing service in IBM API Connect?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

To get started quickly with API Connect, I just want to import a Swagger spec of an existing service and make this service a managed API in API Connect. 
API Connect provides an import function for YAML files, but the API can not be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this scenario several times, so I though it might be useful to have some documentation on this.
When importing a swagger specification, you need to modify a few settings to transform this service definition into an API definition (even though they are quite similar). You need to modify the following parameters:

- Schemes https - The Gateway enforces HTTPS
- Host: $(catalog.host) - This variable links to the current host (in a certain catalog)

Then, you need to build an assembly. The proxy policy is well suited for building facades, as all content from Headers, Body, etc. is re-routed. For the URL, enter the URL of the endpoint + a context variable that refers to the incoming path, like:

```
http://example.com$(request.path)
```

I have created a [small video on Youtube](https://youtu.be/C6j-DKoodHA) to demonstrate the neccessary steps.